# Global.asa file in a mixed application in IIS 7.5 fires for ASP.Net page also

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic, global-asax

I have a web application that has both classic ASP and ASP.Net pages.

In the scenario below, will the session start event also fire in Global.asa when accessing an ASP.Net page?

**A user has bookmarked an ASP.Net page**,  and he is taken to the login page when user tries to access it. **Once the user logs in to this ASP.Net page, Session_Start event fires in Global.asax, but will the same event also fire in Global.asa?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't. `Global.asa` will not be invoked unless any pages in the Classic ASP application are requested.

The only way to force `Session_Start` in Global.asa from your ASP.NET application is by making a `HttpWebRequest` from your ASP.NET application to your Classic application, but you'll need to proxy the request's cookies so the session is adopted by your end user's browser.